# Type-checking with mypy just the function header

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

Is there a way to make python3 mypy typecheck only the function header for type hints, and not variables inside the function?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want that?

Comment: Use case: want function headers to explicitly denote type, but do not care about variables inside the function.

Comment: So you want the check to only be performed during the function invocation based on the types in the header?

Comment: Yes, and I also want to make sure that our team is writing type hints for function headers, but I do not care much if they do not write type hints for variables inside the function. I want mypy to complain if a function header does not have type hints (both parameters and return value), but I do not want it to complain about anything else.